# Rename a column in dataframe based on a list of str variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First I have created a for loop to iterate through a NC file based on the list of "variables".
I have created the code below to convert that list to a dataframe and only consider the rows from 4 to 18.

```
var = data.variables
var = list(var)
var_df = pd.DataFrame(var, columns =['vari']) 
var_df = var_df[4:]
var_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Next, I have created a for loop to extract the corresponding value of the related variable in every iteration.

```
for i, row in var_df.iterrows():
    
    variable = row['vari']
    Z4 = data.variables[variable][:, max_index_lat, max_index_lon]
    e = e.append(pd.DataFrame(Z4))
    e.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

The output is a dataframe with column name of 0.

```
              0
0    285.021257
1    295.074810
2    290.035815
3    300.408855
4    301.481194
..          ...
112  301.276755
113  303.004873
114  303.472141
115  300.157653
116  300.353330

[117 rows x 1 columns]
```

**My question is how can I rename the header of column based on the variables name in each for loop**
for example if the first variable is 'rainfall' the '0' header of the column be named as 'rainfall'.

I have tried the:
e.columns =[variable]
but give me the error:
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 1 elements

Comment: Give us sample input and desired output...

Comment: Can you share what `data` looks like ?

Comment: Maybe try print `e.shape`  and see how many columns it has ?

Comment: No I want the name of dataframe instead of '0' be the name of the variable (variable = row['vari'])

Comment: what I meant is from the error message, it  looks like `e` has  two columns but you are  trying to assign a single element list  to its columns.

Comment: No the first column is index

Comment: Use `.rename()`: `e.rename(columns = {0: string})` where `e` is your DataFrame, and `string` is the variable you are assigning.

Answer (score 0):

Rename column example:

```
df.rename(columns={0: "rainfall"}, inplace=True)
```

This renames column 0 to string rainfall

if you want to change it back

```
df.rename(columns={"rainfall":0}, inplace=True)
```